# Showing response in view Angular Js and Spring MVC

Tags: angularjs, spring

From my rest Controller , I am getting response like :-

```
{"success":true,"response":5}
```

When In my angular Js I use :

```
 {{notificationCount}}
```

It works perfectly and show 5 on my page. But when my response is like :

```
{"success":true,"response":0}
```

For the same {{notificationCount}} , i get error.

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: Showing everything . {"success":true,"response":0} . I just want 0 .

Comment: You need to post relevant code. If you have a Spring `@RestController`, you must have an Angular service that receives objects from it. After that you must be having a call to that service and a variable that receives the value. Also the controller code that contains the line `$scope.notificationCount = <something>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display count only, you can set it like that:

```
{{notificationCount.response}}
```

where

```
notificationCount = //your response
```

Comment: Not working... I dont know why.. in my angular ctrl  $scope.notificationCount = response;

Comment: Could you create plnkr?

Answer (score 0):

json keys should be in single quote like `{'success':true,'response':0}`

```
var data = {"success":true,"response":0};
$scope.notificationCount = data.response;
```

In HTML `{{notificationCount}}` showing 0 (i am checking in Firefox).

Comment: `json keys should be in single quote`. Not necessary.